# select time range in date range fullcalendar vue

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

I am working on VUE project where i can add range date event.
Example

```js
  const eventList = [{
            status: "Pending",
            title: "title",
            start: "2022-10-19",
            end: "2022-10-21",
            // startTime: '10:00',
            // endTime: '12:00',
          }]
```

[image: this code preview month]

[image: this code preview for week]

now what is want to also add time range for every event so that time range can be visible in week page and it should look like

[image: it should look like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing to what you've shown in your question is a simple [recurring event](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events).

For example:

```
{
  status: "Pending",
  title: "title",
  startRecur: "2022-10-19",
  endRecur: "2022-10-21",
  startTime: '10:00',
  endTime: '12:00',
}
```

This will create a series of events occurring between the times specified in `startTime` and `endTime`, which will show on every day between `startRecur` and `endRecur` (the end date being exclusive). See the documentation link above for more details and options.

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ExLBbNO